# Updating a timer label whilst an animation is playing?

Tags: ios, swift, animation, grand-central-dispatch

I run the code

```
DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
   self?.sliderView.elapsedLabel.text = self?.player.currentTime.secondsToString()
}
```

Which every second of an observer firing that watches the audio file progression, will update a label of remaning seconds. It forces main thread because its UI related...

```
player.event.secondElapse.addListener(self, handleAudioPlayerSecondElapsed)
```

Meanwhile I have an animation loop playing in the background using `AVKit`

I am finding that, when the label updates, it stops the animation, as both are real time main thread updates?

How is this handled to allow 2 processes to update the UI at the same time without clashing with each other?

Updated code for the animating video:

```
let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: file)

videoPlayer = AVQueuePlayer(items: [playerItem])
playerLooper = AVPlayerLooper(player: videoPlayer!, templateItem: playerItem)

videoPlayerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: videoPlayer)
videoPlayerLayer!.frame = inView.bounds
videoPlayerLayer!.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill
```

then I call the standard

```
videoPlayer?.play()
```

Comment: It shouldn't do that, you're probably interruption the animation somehow, please provide code of your animation loop

Comment: yep i know its not correct which is why its interrupting, but i wondered if there is ANY way it can work or is this just not possible to have 2 real time UI updating processes running? Ill update the OP but the looping video is a library so not my code

Comment: What I meant to say that if you’re doing all correctly, you can update many ui processes without distribution, that’s why I need to see the code of your animation to see if there’s some problem

Comment: ah ok, ive updated the OP, its just that config and then i call play. Play is a AVKit func and runs on main thread automatically.

Comment: So you have some video which you’re calling an animation loop? Try using profiler, it may show you is there’s a lot of work is done on main thread

Comment: yeah the code is in the OP so you can see the player. Ive never used profiler, id asume theres a lot of work by the nature of that the OP outlines

Comment: Are you testing this with a release build on a physical device? Doing debug build or doing it on the simulator will manifest behaviors you won’t see in production.

Comment: I’m very surprised that you’re having video interrupted, as we frequently use [`addPeriodicTimeObserver`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avplayer/1385829-addperiodictimeobserver) to update a label with the progress during playback without incident, all on the main thread. (I am not familiar with the API associated with the `secondElapse` listener. What is that?) I might suggest editing your question to give us a [reproducible example of the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/MCVE).

Comment: Hi @Rob, its the SwiftAudio library so i cant really make an example as its not all my code! you can find it here https://github.com/jorgenhenrichsen/SwiftAudio it does use addPeriodicTimeObserver to fuel it. The intervals report back fine, its the label update that clashes with the animation player

Comment: is also occurs on device!